# Remove spaces in between words and change from upper case to lower case then transfer to new file

Tags: linux, sed, files

First year learning with Linux a gameshell made by the teacher on a terminal. We are asked to remove spaces in between words horizontally ( besides \n ), change the letters from upper case to lower case and then transfer the result into a new file.

I'm pretty sure this line of command is the good one. 
Once I display it using cat newfile.

This is my line of command :

```
sed -i 's/.*/\U&/' old file | tee newfile
```

However, it doesn't accept it. 
Why doesn't it work? Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 things that I can see:

1. The `\U` modifier converts **to** upper case, whereas you have been asked to convert **from** upper to lower case
2. Your expression doesn't appear to remove spaces at all - this is probably easiest to do as a separate expression e.g. `s/ //g` or (to replace horizontal whitespace more generally) `s/[[:blank:]]//g`
3. Using `-i` (or `--in-place`) doesn't make sense when you want to redirect or pipe the command's output to another file or process.

So putting all these together, you could use

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]//g' -e 's/.*/\L&/' oldfile > newfile
```

---

If you want to modify `oldfile` in place first, and then transfer the content to `newfile` using redirection, you could do that at least in GNU sed using:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/[[:blank:]]//g' -e 's/.*/\L&/' -e 'w /dev/stdout' oldfile | tee newfile
```

Note that you need to write to `/dev/stdout` explicitly since the modified file is not written to standard output by default when the `-i` option is used.

Alternatively (and more simply), move or copy the modified file:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/[[:blank:]]//g' -e 's/.*/\L&/' oldfile && cp oldfile newfile
```

Comment: The reason why I was using -i is to modify the content in the oldfile and then transfer the content to newfile.

Comment: So what does sed -e do exactly ?

Comment: `-e` tells `sed` that the next argument is a script. You can drop it if there is only one script argument: `sed 's/ //g;s/.*/\L&/' oldfile`

Comment: @forzatek I have added some options for in-place processing

Comment: @Philippos thanks for your help !

Comment: @steeldriver is it possible to use mv instead of cp ?

Comment: @forzatek yes it is